# Coordinates for a section corner

Tags: qgis

I would like to acquire the coordinates for a specific corner of a Section.  The Section is Section 12 located as part of/within Township 8 South, Range 2 West.  This section is located in the southwest portion of Mobile County, Alabama.  This Section 12 is shown on the City Map of Mobile (http://maps.cityofmobile.org/citymap).  It is not part of the PLSS data base.

I have ask for this information from the Mobile City/County GIS office.  I think the information given me was 'measured' from the map view itself.  This is not acceptable.

I believe this information (coordinates) could be got from a shapefile in some way.  I have as yet been unable to figure out how to do such. The corner of this section is the beginning point of a survey description of some property my brother has.  We are not surveyors but are interested in gaining more knowledge in our pursuit of understanding the survey itself.

Can you help?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you are dealing with a Coastal Management Zone issue there.
I also do not believe that you will find actual coordinates for that section corner.
There is a very distinct possibility that portion of the township was never surveyed, and broken down into actual sections.
You may want to try to get the information from NOAA, but I do not know where there nearest office is. (Probably New Orleans.)

[image: Mobile County Topo]

If you look at the image, you will see that there are unsurveyed sections for that township.

I believe that coordinates you received were indeed scaled, or interpolated.

Given the proximity of the area to the coast, and the Intracoastal waterway, I do believe NOAA, and Coastal Management would be your best bet for information, rather than a county managed GIS database.

That area is unincorporated, and part of an original land grant so records pertaining to that area may be very sketchy.

If there is an actual found monument for the Section Corner(s) in question, the easiest way to get coordinates for it would be to occupy it with a GPS unit.
A newer handheld unit will give you reasonable accuracy, and the more corners you can find, the better you will be able to retrace the boundary.

Researching the original breakdown survey of that land could end up being very time consuming, and lead you on some wild goose chases retracing the footsteps of the original surveyor(s).